# MySQL Workbench, small characters in the navigation window

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've recently install MySQL Workbench on my new ThinkPad T480s (Windows 10). After installing MySQL Workbench and attempting to utilise it, I realised that this came with extremely small font size (too small to even read without squinting constantly). Hoping to change it, I increased the dpi at the Display settings to 225%, which made the entire display larger (and more readable), but the font size in the app still remained unfathomably small, as you can see from the screenshot.

Can you help me to fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem on HiDPI displays and unfortunately you cannot do much to remedy it. Windows (in opposition to macOS, where the HiDPI support works very well) has got no good API support for high display resolutions. An application has to take care itself to render text and images properly. That requires a lot of changes in MySQL Workbench, which is the reason it didn't happen yet today.

We are aware of this situation and plan to fix that in a future Workbench release. Important here is to voice your demand in the [public issue tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com). The more people complain the higher are chances that things get fixed sooner.

Comment: 3 years later still mini text on macOs